# Find shared folder name and Active directory security group name

Tags: active-directory, network-share

I noticed that the Security Group name in AD didn't match the Shared folder name.(Not created by me). Now I have the folder name but can't seem to find the Group name associated to this shared folder.

Is there a tool I can use?

Comment: Ummm... That's not really how it works. Shared folder names and Security Group names don't have to match and very rarely, if ever, do. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to find what is the group in AD is associated with the folder.

Comment: There's not necessarily any group "associated" with the folder. What you need to do is to look at the existing Share and NTFS permissions on the folder to see which users and groups have access. Then determine which users and groups should have access and adjust the permissions accordingly.

Comment: The way I'm reading this, it sounds like you typically follow a convention where security groups that are assigned to share/ntfs permissions are named in a such a way as to be apparent what folder's access list it's been attached to (e.g. one would name a group Share_Accounting_Modify and then add a modify access control entry on \\server\accting for that group).  Is this what you mean when you say it doesn't match?  I'm also confused because in the first part of your question, it sounds like you know the name of the group and not the folder, but in the second part it's reversed.

Comment: Yes Dawn. I meant that I have a folder named Share_Accounting but I can't seem to find the relevant security groups that are assigned to this folder. When I checked the security, it just show the users that has access to that folder while other folders has the security group.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for us to help you identify which group should have access to the folder. There's no official standard for naming security groups. There's no technical "rule" that says a security group name should resemble the resources it's meant to secure. The group name could literally be ANYTHING. What you need to do is use a little intuition and a little guessing and look for a security group whose name matches the "type" of folder and the "type" of data in the folder. If the folder is related to HR and contains HR data then look for a group related to the members of the HR department. If user accounts have been granted access to the folder then go talk to those users to get an idea of who should have access to the folder and then look for a group whose members contain those users.

There's no tool that can tell you which group should have access to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be going to the folder's location (using the full path \server\folder), right-click and check it's properties, in the security tab should be listed which security folders are linked to it. Hope this helped! :)